# Unable to see Pivot List Application Template - silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7, pivot

I am trying to create a Pivot List Application with Panorama view using Silverlight for Windows Phone. On some demo website and in some online tutorial, I was able to see an Installed Template by name Windows Phone Pivot List Application in VS2010. But When I open my VS2010 Express for Windows Phone, I could see only 3 options under Silverlight for Windows Phone.
a) Windows Phone Application, b) Windows Phone List Application c) Windows Phone Class Library. I dont see Windows Phone Pivot List Application. I tried to integrate Pivot controls in a List Application, but I was failing for a succesful run.

My Question 1: How do I get Windows Phone Pivot List Application under my installed Templates?
Question 2: Is it possible to create a project from List Application Template and later integrate Pivot Controls in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1.
It sounds like you're stil using the CTP. You need to upgrade to the RTM/RTW version to get these templates.

You can [get the download from create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)

Q2.
Once you have the new templates you also get the ability to add new pages which contain pivot or panorama controls by default too.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Its been a while since I downloaded the VS and started to use it like last week.